# Python - what should and shouldn't be tested

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, python-unittest

I'm trying to understand what should and shouldn't be tested. Even after reading other questions/answers on S.O., I still didn't really understand it. One of the senior devs at my work says all my code should be tested, but it seems asinine to tests parts of it – i.e. when those parts only use code that has already been tested.

The following example has a **http request function** and a **get username function**. All the **get username function** does is call the **http request function**. Because I'm using Testbed, there is no HTTP request that gets sent out, so we're not testing correctness of returned data. So should I still test the **get username function**?

Code from the file being tested

```
def fetch_url(url, method=urlfetch.GET, data=''):
    """Send a HTTP request"""

    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, method=method, payload=data,
                            headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})

    return result.content


def get_user_name():
    """Get the name of the current user"""

    url = '{}/user?access_token={}'.format(GITHUB_API_URL, get_access_token())

    result = json.loads(fetch_url(url))

    return result['login']
```

Here is the test:

```
class TestUrlFetch(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test if fetch_url sending legitimate requests"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_urlfetch_stub()

    def test_fetch_url(self):
        from console.auth import fetch_url

        # Grab content via a URL fetch
        content = fetch_url('https://google.com')

        # Test that content is not empty
        self.assertIsNotNone(content)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()
```

So as asked above, should I write another test to test the `get_user_name` function?

Comment: You might get better answer from: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: get_user_name() seems to format a string in a specific way and parse some json.  Perhaps you might skip testing fetch_url() and only test get_user_name().. but then how would you test URLs that don't look like `'{}/user?access_token={}'.format(GITHUB_API_URL, get_access_token())`?  General rule is, test anything that might be reused by code that doesn't currently exist.  Which is: everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems asinine to tests parts of it – i.e. when those parts only use code that has already been tested.

How do you know that you're using those parts correctly, together?

Unit tests are there to quickly trap programming errors - bugs and changes in interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. Hard to learn this stuff completely by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the testing methodology, but I think testing every line of code is a good idea for code that will need to be maintained. That doesn't mean every line needs its own test. You can use tools like [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/) to see which lines your tests do cover.